# Using your own credentials in Nodejs app, is it safe?

Tags: node.js

is it save to upload your nodejs application that uses your own credentials to login?

Edited : I am using my password and username -I am storing them in json file and reading form this file- to login into my account in an automated way, is it save to host this app or this will be threaten my privacy?

Comment: Are the credentials entered in the code, or are they user inputs.

Comment: Please add further details in description. Your question seems so vogue. what do you mean by your own credential to login? Every users has his own credential to login  any app.

Comment: I edited my question above, is it clear now?

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid storing your password anywhere, you could commit your code to Github with the password (very common) and your password could be publicly available, also you need to be able to trust the place you are going to be hosting your server. You should make use of something like Azure Key Vault for storing your passwords if you are using Azure. If your application has to have the password stored then have it hashed and salted, revealing of the hash and salted password will not be as bad as revealing your password.

Comment: regarding the hosting part, any recommendation for free platform? Azure key Vault new words mmmm? how I can hash my passwords and using its hashing within the app, any links?

Answer (score 1):

You should never store username and password in the JSON file as you will pushing the code to GitHub or bitbucket. Storing password will be very much vulnerable. Instead of that you can store encrypted version of password or you can use database for storing username and password.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean storing username & password for the last user that logged-in, the common approach is storing a token in the app.

I'm guessing you are logging in to an online service that you coded:

For instance login through the app to the server, get a token in exchange, next time for auto login instead of username & password send that token, if token still valid (time limit, or login from another location should change/delete token in the server) then the server should respond you as you are logged in.

If it is something else;

Like an offline app, but that still requires a login, if they create a user account in the app;
a) Hash user's password with an encryption library something like CryptoJS https://github.com/brix/crypto-js 
But remember do not bundle password with the app, on first launch ask for password then store it. So you can avoid accidental password share.

From docs:

```
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

// Encrypt
var ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt('my message', 'secret key 123').toString();

// Decrypt
var bytes  = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertext, 'secret key 123');
var originalText = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

console.log(originalText); // 'my message'
```

b) just make the app remember username only, make the user use the password.

What you are going to follow depends on what are you trying to achieve and how your app works.

Comment: What I am trying to do is the following, I used puppeteer and corn libraries in an automated script written in nodejs to login into my Discord account then react to a message sent by the mentor as a sign of my presence, to login into my account I need my username and password which I stored in json file, the problem is that my script run at 9am daily to put an attendance, but if my laptop was sleep it won't work, so I need to host it some where without make password and email in plain text format, could you help me plz?

Comment: Then I already answered your question. There is a link to a library above. You can use that.